# Get value of UUID() after insert?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I'm using JDBC + mysql. I am inserting a record and using UUID() in my statement. I'm wondering if we can get the generated UUID value out of the ResultSet?:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO foo(name, random),
    VALUES(john, UUID())");
ResultSet generatedKeys = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
// any way to find out the value of the UUID() result?
```

Yeah so I am just wondering if I can get whatever value UUID() generates above without having to select the record again.

Thanks

Comment: You need to SELECT - you could've used `LAST_INSERTED_ID` if it were an autonumber column...

Comment: Bummer, ok gotcha. Can you put that as an answer, I don't think I can accept your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set and select user variable, for example -

```
SET @uuid = UUID();
INSERT INTO foo(name, random) VALUES(john, @uuid);
SELECT @uuid;
```